# Apex Trigger not considering system context currency code

Tags: apex, trigger

Our System is multi currency enabled with Advanced currency management. My requirement is get the currency in USD(corporate currency) on a given Opportunity and stamp it to a custom field.

I have written Apex trigger on Opportunity object by using `convertCurrency` function knowing the fact that `convertCurrency` returns value in user local currency.

I thought since Apex trigger is running in system context it would take the `DEFAULTCURRENCYISOCODE` from the user object as "USD" on system context. Apparently that is not the case.

Is that possible that the following code will take "USD" as the `DEFAULTCURRENCYISOCODE` to return the corporate currency value?

```
    trigger CopyConvertedValue on Opportunity (after insert,after update )
{
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
    //List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new Map<Id,Opportunity>();
    for(Opportunity Oppty: Trigger.New){
      if(Trigger.isInsert){      
        oppIds.add(Oppty.Id);
        System.debug('I am inside'+userinfo.getDefaultCurrency());
      }
      else if((Oppty.Amount_2__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(Oppty.Id).Amount_2__c ) || Trigger.oldMap.get(Oppty.Id).TriggerToSE__c == 'ConvertForMkto' )
      {
        oppIds.add(Oppty.Id);
        System.debug('Iam edit'+userInfo.getDefaultCurrency());
      }
    }
    if(!oppIds.isEmpty()){
      for (Opportunity opp : [SELECT Converted_Amount_2__c,convertCurrency(Amount_2__c) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds]){
        oppsToUpdate.put((Id)opp.get('Id'),new Opportunity(Id=(Id)opp.get('Id'),Converted_Amount_2__c = (Double)opp.Amount_2__c,TriggerToSE__c=null));
      }
    }
    if(oppsToUpdate.size()>0){
      Database.update(oppsToUpdate.values(),false);
    }
}
```

For example when creating an Opportunity with currency code as "Korean Won" the debug statement is returning that particular user default currency code.

[image]

Comment: What determines where the currency code comes from? Is it based on the owner of the Opportunity?

Comment: Currency code is coming from Opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve with the following approach.

```
    trigger CopyConvertedValue on Opportunity (before insert ,before update )
{

   Map<ID,DatedConversionRate> isoWithRateMap = new Map<ID,DatedConversionRate>([SELECT NextStartDate,StartDate,IsoCode,ConversionRate FROM DatedConversionRate]);

  if (checkRecursive.runOnce()){
    for(Opportunity opp: trigger.new){      

        Decimal convertedValue;
        for (DatedConversionRate dcr: isoWithRateMap.values()) {
          if (dcr.isoCode != opp.CurrencyIsoCode)                                   continue;   // look for a match in table against input currency
          if (opp.CloseDate < dcr.startDate || opp.CloseDate >= dcr.nextStartDate)  continue;
          convertedValue =  opp.Amount_2__c / dcr.conversionRate;
          break;
        }
        opp.Converted_Amount_2__c = convertedValue;    

      }
    }
}
```